# apt-get update fails on debian on google compute engine

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine

Updating repositories information and installing packages is failing on a debian instance on google-compute-engine with the following error:

```
E: Release file for http://gce_debian_mirror.storage.googleapis.com/dists/wheezy-updates/Release is expired (invalid since 5h 44min 5s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

It seems that there is a problem with the repository (or I am missing something).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is due to expired support for the mirror.  I had success with the following commands:

```
sudo aptitude -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

As a side note/question, I find that deploying a hadoop cluster on google compute engine is failing this morning as well (e.g., directory /home/hadoop is empty).  Just wondering if any google reviewers could comment on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Had trouble also to launch a simple LAMP template. It seems a general issue somewhere.

Comment: This is correct, Google engineers are working to get this fixed as soon as possible. In the meantime, the way to apply the same "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until" fix to bdutil is by modifying libexec/bdutil_helpers.sh and changing each "apt-get <arguments> <command>" to read "apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false <arguments> <command>". There should be three instances (two apt-get updates and one apt-get install) that need be updated.

Answer (score 1):

How about using temporarily the default Debian sources.list until Google fixes the problem with their mirror?

For Debian7, the list is here: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

You can also use a sources.list generator: http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: Yes, thought so also but wanted to report it for any google engineer to check.